# Ruby - rails - how to create automatic hyperlinks for urls in the text/string rendered on the view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create automatic hyperlinks for urls in the text/string rendered on the view? 
I have a page that renders user activity log and in that log/text/string there are some random   urls which I want to automatically hyperlink to open in a new browser window. There is this `auto_link` in ruby rails, how do I use that?

```
text = "User xyz accessed url - http://www.something.com on 04/13/2012 00:13:18GMT"

<%= "#{Text}" %>
```

I want this rendered with a hyperlink to the url. The URL could be anything anywhere in the text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use auto_link like this:

```
<%= auto_link(text) %>
```

If you want the generated links to open new browser windows (or tabs) add the option like so:

```
<%= auto_link(text, :html => { :target => '_blank' }) %>
```

As mentioned by pjumble in the comments, `auto_link` is no longer a part of Rails core as of Rails 3.1, this gem brings it back: https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink Thanks pjumble!

Comment: Tried that `<%= auto_link("#{text}") %>`. Got this error - `undefined method 'auto_link' for #<#<Class:0xb0c3928>:0xb116524>`

Comment: in the view - `<% @a[:log].to_s.split(/---/).reverse.each do |line| %>
<div width="100%" height="auto"><pre class="log"><%= auto_link(line) %></pre></div>
<% end %>`

Comment: `auto_link` was removed in Rails 3.1 (extracted to a separate gem: https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink)

Comment: Great! thanks guys! Install the gem and it worked! 
Hey pjumble add your comment as answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @Firstname Lastname: Thanks but I would accept ctcherrys' answer. I didn't know about the `auto_link` function until reading this answer, then out of interest looking it up in the rails guide (which linked to the gem).

Answer (score 3):

For faster parsing, try https://github.com/vmg/rinku

```
require 'rinku'
Rinku.auto_link(text, mode=:all, link_attr=nil, skip_tags=nil)
```

Also one often need more filters than just linking, for example Youtube embedded videos. For this use: https://github.com/dejan/auto_html